# Order an std::map by the absolute value of key

Tags: c++, dictionary

I want to order an `std::map` by the absolute value of key with following code as the usual customized order

```
vector<int> A = {-4,4,-2,2};
auto cmp = [](int a, int b) { return abs(a) < abs(b); };
map<int, int, decltype(cmp)> m(cmp);
for (int x : A)  m[x]++;
```

But the result is `m = {{-4,2},{-2,2}}`. I don't know, why the key `4` and  `2` are missing.  I want to keep all values and actually I don't care about the `=` i.e. `4,-4` and `-4,4` are both ok for me. I only what to order them when the values are different.

Comment: Give an example input and output for your problem.

Comment: @Dr.Gut I just want to count the frequency of the number in A. so the value of the may is the frequency of key. The result I want is `map<int,int> m ={{2,1},{-2,1},{-4,1},{4,1}}` and the order exchanged between the keys with same absolute value are allowed (I mean the result such as {-2,1},{2,1}... is also acceptable, but `-4` and `4` must set after `-2` and `2`), it it possible to get such result?

Comment: OK. Here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63094406/11279879).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To order the `int` keys as `0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, ...` change the comparator to this ([live](https://godbolt.org/z/vETGr6)):

```
auto cmp = [](int a, int b) { return abs(a) != abs(b) ? abs(a) < abs(b) : a > b; };
```

This comparator uses [lexicographical comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) with two sort keys:

1. The absolute value of the number.
2. The sign of the number.

Answer (score 4):

Your comparison function causes your map to treat keys `4` and `-4` as equivalent.  Ditto for keys `2` and `-2`, so that explains the results you get, since keys in a `map` must be unique.

Comment: I think you could provide a multimap example for completion

Comment: You could perhaps consider using a [`std::multimap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap)

Answer (score 4):

As other answers mention, your comparison operator renders the keys like `4` and `-4` equal, as far as the map is concerned.

### Solution

You can create your own ordering (with a custom comparison operator) to achieve what you want:

```
auto cmp = [](int a, int b) { 
        auto aa = abs(a);
        auto bb = abs(b);
        
        return (2 * aa + (aa == a)) < (2 * bb + (bb == b)); 
    };
```

outputs:

> {-2, 1} {2, 1} {-4, 1} {4, 1}

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6daf1d387d6efa7)

### Explanation

The numbers -4, -2, 2, 4 and so on are **integers**. Inside the comparison function, you can map them to to **natural** numbers and create a tie breaker for positive ones by:

- taking the absolute of double the negative numbers
- taking the absolute of double the positive + 1

So your keys `K = {k1, k2, ... kn}` behave as

```
K' = {k1', k2', ..., kn'} where 

     / 2 * ki, ki < 0
ki' = 
     \ 2 * ki + 1, ki > 0
```

Comment: that's exactly what I want!

Comment: @user6703592 haha then why you unticked?

Comment: sorry, your answer is also very nice, but I think Dr. Gut's idea is more universal for such case. Thanks for the same.

Answer (score 3):

If you check the `std::map` documentation [from cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map):

> Everywhere the standard library uses the Compare requirements, uniqueness is determined by using the equivalence relation. In imprecise terms, two objects `a` and `b` are considered equivalent (not unique) if neither compares less than the other: `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`.

Because of that, after you've already inserted -4, it will work out that neither of 4 and -4 are less than the other, so deem them equal and increment that `map` value.  If you'd inserted 4 first, you would have had a single entry for `4` instead of `-4`.

Personally, I consider this confusing and would recommend using a `std::map<int, int>` and `for (auto a : A) m[abs(a)]++;`.

Comment: sorry, what does `abs(*a)` mean here? `a` is not a points for `int A[4] = { -4,2,-2,4 }`

Comment: @user6703592: yes - sorry - typo.

Comment: `abs(a) <= abs(b)` doesn't work because then equal elements would test unequal.  Any comparison operator you provide is expected to have vaguely sane behaviour modelling a `<` relationship, not `<=`.

Comment: but `m[abs(a)]++` does not solve my issue, i want to keep all keys ordered by absolute value.

Comment: Oh - so you want 4 and -4 to both be keys in the set?  Then I suggest you have a `std::map<int, std::pair<int, int>>`, then you can do `if (a < 0) ++m[abs(a)].first; else ++m(abs(a).second;` - keeping separate tallies for the negative and positive "4"s.

Comment: @user6703592 you cant use `abs()` to order elements of a `map` and still be able to have separate elements for positive and negative values of the same absolute value. This sounds like an XY problem. What are you REALLY trying to accomplish? Sounds like you probably should use a `vector<pair<int, int>>` instead and then order it as needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau let me clearify, actually i don't care `=` i.e. `4,-4` and `-4,4` are both ok for me. I only what to order them when the values are different.

Comment: @user6703592 I don't understand what you are saying. But you CAN'T have `map[-4]` and `map[4]` as distinct elements when using `abs()` for the comparator. `map` simple doesn't work that way.

Comment: sorry the result I want is `map<int,int> m ={{2,1},{-2,1},{-4,1},{4,1}}` and the order between the the key with the same absolute is not important.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the result I want is `map<int,int> m ={{2,1},{-2,1},{-4,1},{4,1}}` and the order exchanged between the keys with same absolute value are allowed (I mean the result such as {-2,1},{2,1}... is also acceptable), it it possible to get such result?